# SQL Server's ow "batchparser.dll" - how to use it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-parser, tsql-parser

Is there a documented or at least vaguely documented way to make use of the SQL Server `batchparser.dll` that's hidden away deep inside the SQL Server directory structure (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn`)?

Would that be a possibility to submit a T-SQL batch and have it parsed for syntax errors?

Comment: Not an answer, but have you tried loading it in something like PowerShell that's easy to probe with?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.batchparser(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on David Brabant's link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.batchparser(v=sql.110).aspx) this dll just parses the input text into batches (e.g. text between separate GO statements). The specific function to do the parsing is

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.batchparser.batchparser.parse(v=sql.110).aspx

You might find the TSqlParser class more useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser.aspx

or SqlParser namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser(v=sql.120).aspx